# Difference between a central potential that is a point and one that is a sphere?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

In quantum physics there is a special case known as a [particle in a spherically symmetric potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_spherically_symmetric_potential). I have a problem which is similar to the case of a hydrogen atom in that there is one free electron, but the "nucleus" is actually a group of several atoms. So I'm not sure how to find the radial wavefunction for this situation? If I could say that it's a point charge I could use the same radial wavefunction as for the hydrogen atom (I think). But since the group of atoms takes up space, how does that affect the potential/wavefunction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the radial equation piecewise. [Here](http://ocw.usu.edu/physics/classical-mechanics/pdf_lectures/31.pdf) it is an example done in perturbation theory, but because the radial and angular parts of the Hamiltonian separate out, you can probably find a way to get an analytic solution. The first approximation here is to treat the "ball o' atoms" as a [uniformly charged sphere](http://www.phys.uri.edu/~gerhard/PHY204/tsl94.pdf).

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 0):

In effect you're trying to calculate the wavefunction for a molecule i.e. the molecular orbitals. There is no simple solution for this. Three decades ago when I was doing this sort of thing we used a [Hartree-Fock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) self consistent field calculation to compute the molecular orbitals on an IBM mainframe. I imagine that these days the calculation is trivial and you'd be able to do it on your PC (or phone :-).

The highly excited states, where the electron has a high probability of being a long way from the nuclei, will resemble the hydrogen atomic orbitals. However the ground state will be very different.